# SQL Server - Compare 2 tables for data existing in the same columns without checking for equality

Tags: sql-server, comparison

**Update:**

Unfortunately, the answer provided here did not give me what I wanted - My mistake for accepting too quickly without really doing a deep enough check.

I have reported the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51972449/1693085).

---

Suppose I have the following two tables in my SQL Server (2012) DB:

**Tbl1:**

```
ID:     Col1:     Col2:     Col3:
1       Val1      Val2      Val3
2       <NULL>    Val2      <NULL>
3       Val1      <NULL>    Val3
4       Val1      <NULL>    Val3
```

**Tbl2:**

```
ID:     Col1:     Col2:     Col3:
1       Val1      Val2      Val3
2       <NULL>    Val2      <NULL>
3       <NULL>    <NULL>    Val3
5       <NULL>    <NULL>    Val3
```

And, at this point, all I want to see is:

1. Any rows that are in one table but not the other (based on `ID` pk)
2. If the `ID` is in both tables, then are the same columns populated (not caring specifically about the values yet).

I'm just trying to come up with a SQL to just let me know which `ID`s have discrepancies.

My ideal output would look as follows:

```
Tbl1_ID:       Tbl2_Id:       Discrepancy:
1              1              0
2              2              0
3              3              1
4              <NULL>         1
<NULL>         5              1
```

My testing SQL so far is this:

```
DECLARE 
@Tbl1 TABLE (ID INT, Col1 VARCHAR(10), Col2 VARCHAR(10), Col3 VARCHAR(10))
;
DECLARE
@Tbl2 TABLE (ID INT, Col1 VARCHAR(10), Col2 VARCHAR(10), Col3 VARCHAR(10))
;

INSERT INTO @Tbl1 (ID, Col1, Col2, Col3)
VALUES
    (1, 'Val1', 'Val2', 'Val3')
    ,(2, NULL   , 'Val2', NULL)
    ,(3, 'Val1', NULL, 'Val3')
    ,(4, 'Val1', NULL, 'Val3')
;

INSERT INTO @Tbl2 (ID, Col1, Col2, Col3)
VALUES
    (1, 'Val1', 'Val2', 'Val3')
    ,(2, NULL   , 'Val2', NULL)
    ,(3, NULL, NULL, 'Val3')
    ,(5, NULL, NULL, 'Val3')
;


SELECT
     [@Tbl1].ID AS Tbl1_ID
    ,[@Tbl2].ID AS Tbl2_ID
    , -- Some kind of comparison to let me know if all columns are populated the same
     AS Discrepancy
FROM
    @Tbl1
    FULL JOIN @Tbl2
    ON [@Tbl1].ID = [@Tbl2].ID
```

---

Is there some good way to accomplish this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

For the discrepancy column, just use a case statement.

```
case when [@Tbl1].ID = [@Tbl2].ID then 0 else 1 end
```

Or for all columns...

```
case case when [@Tbl1].ID = [@Tbl2].ID 
               and isnull([@Tbl1].Col1,'random') = isnull([@Tbl2].Col1,'random')
               and ...
               then 0 else 1 end
```

Comment: no, `NULL` is the lack of a value, so it would be a discrepancy. Would you want nulls ignored?

Comment: Yes - I said it in the question - If both tables have `NULL` in the same column then it's ok.

Comment: That would do it! - DUH!

Comment: No worries, i should have read better. You asked a clear question +1

Comment: THANK YOU for the fast response - Just annoyed I didn't think of that! :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I was too quick to assume the answer was correct - Unfortunately, this still checks the values in `Tbl1.ColX` with those in `Tbl2.ColX` whereas, at this point, I just want to check is both columns are populated **without a comparison on values directly** - I, unfortunately, had to re-ask the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51972449/1693085
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: If you asked a new question after finding new details why remove this one as accepted which doesn’t affect your new question. Quite odd. Anywho I’ll look at the new one

Comment: I don't mind leaving this as the accepted answer - I just didn't want someone who was looking at this and had the **exact same issue** to assume this was correct since this does compare values whereas the question states I did not want to compare.